# Why the density plot of a vector with uniqe numbers is a normal distribution?

Tags: r

The density plot of vector that containing unique number is normal distribution with mean 1:

For example:

```
plot(density(rep(1,100))
```

Answer (score 2):

The `density` functions performs [kernel density estimation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation), which roughly works as follows:

On each observation, a small "bump" shaped like a normal distribution (or similar) is placed; the final curve is then simply the sum of all the small bumps. When all small bumps are identical, namely a normal distribution with mean 1, also the final curve will be a normal distribution with mean 1.

Answer (score 1):

This is answered in the documentation ?density ... there is a parameter kernel which defaults to gaussian.  If what you are looking for is uniform density add `kernel="rectangular"`.

`plot(density(rep(1,100), kernel="rectangular"))`

Other options are "triangular", "epanechnikov", "biweight", "cosine" or "optcosine".

Answer (score 1):

The density function sets several defaults which can largely determine the result.  In particular, it sets kernel = "gaussian" which explains the shape of the curve.  More importantly for your case, its sets bw = the bandwidth given by the bw.nrd0() function which uses the standard deviation and interquartile distance to estimate a bandwidth unless these quantities are zero as they are in your case.  In this situation, it uses  0.9 * abs(x[1]) * length(x)^(-0.2) which in your case is 0.3582965 as displayed in your plot which isn't isn't a very good estimate for this data set.  Try manually setting the bw to small quantities such as .01 and .001 and you'll see better approximations to your distribution.

```
plot(density(rep(1,100), bw=.001))
```

You question shows the importance of verifying that the density kernel actually does approximate the input distribution when doing these sorts of calculations.